# lightning:recordEditForm not showing lookup search window in community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, partner-communities, lightning-recordeditform

I'm using lightning:recordEditForm to create new opportunity my code is

```
        <aura:attribute name="objAPIName" type="String" default="Opportunity"/>
             <lightning:recordEditForm
                                     aura:id="editRRForm"
                                     objectApiName="{!v.objAPIName}"                                                      
                                     onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                                     onerror="{!c.handleFormError}"
                                     >
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Class__c" aura:id="editFormField"/>
<lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save"/>    
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Where Class__c is a Lookup field. Problem is when I try to search the lookup field(by typing something and clicking standard search option popped below the field). It's not showing the search window in the community but working fine in Org.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's because a Guest user has no access to edit field's values ([discussion](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005X0PQAU), [and one more](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmBoQAK&title=picklist-fields-do-not-render-for-community-users-when-they-are-used-in-ightning-recordeditform))

And the problem seems to exist nowadays

---

Try to open the console section in your chrome's devtools (or whatever you use). Is there any error?

Comment: Community user is not supposed to have any access issue. Yeah, in console it's giving an error as ------- aura_prod.js:789 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'na' of undefined
    at Object.dispatchGlobalEvent (aura_prod.js:789)
    at a (lightning-overlay-utils.js:2)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Promise.all.then.a (lightning-overlay-utils.js:2)

Comment: @VDahiya so have you tried to launch your community in incognito to check access as a guest user? What about an error you get... I believe you didn't use js promises so the problem seems to be at lightning framework itself

Comment: In incognito also same error is occurring. I don't know much about JS promises. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue what is your option here. How good you are at debugging via devtool?

Comment: Not an expert but have some needful debugging skills.

Comment: @VDahiya ok, so can you handle where exactly does it failed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87072/discussion-between-being-of-habits-and-vdahiya).